# Partial specialization in c++ template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I have a template class to print out the elements in vector. I have both for pointer and reference version.

```
// HEADER
class Util {
...
template <class T>
static void print(const std::vector<T>* vectorArray);

template <class T>
static void print(const std::vector<T>& vectorArray);
...
static void printByteStream(const std::vector<unsigned char>& input);
...
}; 

// BODY
template <class T>
void Util::print(const std::vector<T>* vectorArray)
{
    for (auto i = vectorArray->begin(); i != vectorArray->end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << ":";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void Util::print(const std::vector<T>& vectorArray)
{
    return Util::print(&vectorArray);
}

template void Util::print(const std::vector<int>* vectorArray);
template void Util::print(const std::vector<std::string>* vectorArray);
template void Util::print(const std::vector<int>& vectorArray);
template void Util::print(const std::vector<std::string>& vectorArray);
```

I also have a print code for byte stream.

```
void Util::printByteStream(const std::vector<unsigned char>& input)
{
    for (auto val : input) printf("\\x%.2x", val);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I want to teach the C++ compiler that when I call print with T == unsigned char, call the printByteStream with partial specialization.

I added this code in the body.

```
void Util::print(const std::vector<unsigned char>& vectorArray)
{
    return Util::printByteStream(vectorArray);
}
```

When compiled, the C++ compiler complains that it can't find matching code. What might be wrong?

```
error: prototype for 'void Util::print(const std::vector<unsigned char>&)' does not match any in class 'Util'
 void Util::print(const std::vector<unsigned char>& vectorArray)
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Util`?

Comment: Your generic implementation can't go in a separate file, if that's what you mean by "body".

Comment: Well, it can, as long as all the required specializations are explicitly instantiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add an empty template

```
template <>
void Util::print(const std::vector<unsigned char>& vectorArray)
{
    return Util::printByteStream(vectorArray);
}
```

I have to check. I don't have VS on this computer though.